# [Q]uestion about reading and saving a large txt-file via {RSQLite} line by line into a DB

Tags: sql, database, r, sqlite, large-files

Since my hardware is very limited (a dual core with 32bit Win7 and 4GB of ram - I need to make the best of it.....) I try to save a large text-file (about 1.2GB) into a DB, which I can then trigger by SQL-like queries to do some analytics on particular subgroups.

To be honest I'm not familiar with this area and since I could not find help regarding my issues via "googling", I just quickly show what I came up with and how I thought things would look like:

First I check how many columns my txt-file has:

```
k <- length(scan("data.txt", nlines=1, sep="\t", what="character"))
```

Then I open a connection to the text file so that it does not need to be opened 
again for every single line:

```
filecon<-file("data.txt", open="r")
```

Then I initialize a connection (dbcon) to an SQLite database

```
dbcon<- dbConnect(dbDriver("SQLite"), dbname="mydb.dbms")
```

I find out where the position of the first line is

```
pos<-seek(filecon, rw="r")
```

Since the first line contains the column-names I save them for later use

```
col_names <- unlist(strsplit(readLines(filecon, n=1), "\t"))
```

Next, I test to read the first 10 lines, line by line,
and save them into a DB, which themself (should) contain k - columns with columns-names = col_names.

```
for(i in 1:10) {  

    # prints the iteration number in hundreds
    if(i %% 100 == 0) {      
    print(i)   
    }   

# read one line into a variable tt
tt<-readLines(filecon, n=1)   

# parse tt into a variable tt2, since tt is a string
tt2<-unlist(strsplit(tt, "\t"))

# Every line, read and parsed from the text file, is immediately saved 
# in the SQLite database table "results" using the command dbWriteTable()
dbWriteTable(conn=dbcon, name="results", value=as.data.frame(t(tt2[1:k]),stringsAsFactors=T), col.names=col_names, append=T)


    pos<-c(pos, seek(filecon, rw="r"))
}
```

If I run this I get the following error

```
Warning messages:
1: In value[[3L]](cond) :
  RS-DBI driver: (error in statement: table results has 738 columns but 13 values were supplied)
```

Why should I supply 738 columns? If I change k (which is 12) to 738, the code works but then I need to trigger the columns by V1, V2, V3,.... and not by the column-names I intended to supply

```
res <- dbGetQuery(dbcon, "select V1, V2, V3, V4, V5, V6 from results")
```

Any help or even a small hint is very much appreciated!

Comment: How did you create the `results` table?

Comment: As far as I understand it, the `results` table gets created with the `dbWriteTable` call which creates a key (name `results`) in which, as long as I dont close the connection, a new line gets stored every time the loop runs over the index i.